# Is a 401k contribution fair game for cost cutting?

Tags: 401k, budget

2016 is almost here, and with it, unavoidable increases in health care costs and other expenses.  A budget that was balanced in 2015 might now be out of balance and costs have to be cut somewhere.

Is a 401k fair game for cost cutting?  Should one only make 401k contributions when they can reasonably expect to be cash flow positive (on what time scale?  to what degree of certainty?), or should they always "pay themselves first" (into the 401k) and just expect that things will somehow work out?

What factors specific to retirement and/or a 401k should be considered when making this decision?

Comment: I'm $10 over my monthly budget. Should I cancel my Netflix or Hulu subscription? (Your question isn't quite that bad, but I think it probably is still too opinion based...)

Comment: Indeed - this is an opinion based question. You need a more specifically tailored question if you want to get something useful out of it.

Comment: "Ignoring all other considerations" <---- this trivializes the question as bringing up anything would be some other consideration, no?

Comment: @Joe  People say "don't quit your job until you have another one lined up."  Is that opinion based?  Sure, but it is sound advice which serves the majority of employees well because it is based on sound reasoning.   I'm open to ideas on how to make this a better question.

Comment: "What decision should I make" is opinion based.  Figuring out what specific elements go into making that decision, and then asking about factors affecting *those*, is not opinion based.

Comment: @JBKing Well, I'm looking for good reasons why a 401k specifically should or should not be considered as part of cost cutting. Are you suggesting there is a trivial answer to this question?

Comment: @Michael Sure, but "Should I quit my job before I have another one lined up?" is still opinion based (regardless of the fact that it has a common answer).  Every situation has differences, and undoubtedly some people should quit their jobs before lining another up - hence asking about specific issues that contribute to the decision, rather than the whole decision.

Comment: That really does get at the heart of things though, @Michael.  "Always invest in your 401k up to the match" is basically the personal finance version of that.  So the question is, are there reasons that's not true?  Sure.  What reasons are you looking at, though.  What factors are different in your case that might make it different?

Comment: @Joe Are you saying that I should ask a less general question because there is no common answer or because it might not apply to my situation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33177/discussion-between-michael-and-joe).

Comment: @Joe and JBKing - I just edited the question in an attempt to follow your line of thinking.

Comment: @Joe when dealing with opinion based questions, point them to this post which details stack exchange's philosophy on such matters: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: You don't mention either the matching percent, nor the percent you are currently depositing.

Comment: The question presents a false dichotomy: cut 401k contributions, or just hope things work out. The answer may be neither; keep 401k contributions as-is and then make it work out (don't just hope).

Comment: @stannius By "hope things work out" I meant do things like cut planned maintenance expenses and hope my more conservative estimates weren't really needed, i.e. don't plan for the worst case.

Answer (score 6):

Cut other expenses first.  If you've already done so and still can't make ends meet,  try again. If there is still a problem, consider cutting the 401k back to just enough to maximize the employer match -- anything below that and you're leaving free money on the table.  If that isn't sufficient you may need expert advice to get yourself out of the hole you're in.

Answer (score 4):

I would say no.

If you save a dollar on your current expenses (car payment, electricity, groceries, etc.) you have given up a dollar in value to your lifestyle. If you forego contributing a dollar to your retirement accounts, then you are giving up a dollar and possibly decades of investment gains on that dollar. So I'd say it would be "penny-wise, pound foolish" to do so.

In essence you are taking money from your elderly (probably fixed income) self to pay for something today.

Final Note: It is a huge mistake to wait until some fictional future time when you have more disposable income to start saving. You will NEVER feel like you have excess money for saving. Just bite the bullet, and save whatever you can now. The total time your assets are invested is one of the most important factors, and that only gets shorter the longer you wait.

Answer (score 4):

Other than the already mentioned advice of maxing out the employer match, another consideration in favor of keeping the 401k is that typically 401k plans are tax-deferred (unless it's a Roth 401k), and so the same amount of money goes further with your 401k. For example, if you contribute $100 less to your 401k, you may only take home $70 more that you can use toward expenses.